# Android - How to make a visible element push other elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I got a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ButtonBackspace"
        android:completionHint="@string/a_string"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/a_string"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ButtonBackspace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dialer_btn_bks" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="New"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The visibility of `myButton` starts as Gone. I was hoping that when I change the visibility of the button in run time to Visible, it would push the `ImageButton` and `AutoCompleteTextView` to the left but both the button and imageButton appear on top of each other since they both got `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. I tried adding the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myButton"` to the `ImageButton` but that did not work.

How can I make the button push the other elemets when it become visible and have its own space?

Comment: if these elements are just next to each other, you can use a linear layout and set the gravity to right. the linear layout automatically pushes the elements. in relative layout all elements are "relative" to another object or the parent view.

Comment: I used it and it works but I don't really like the answer since it seems like ignoring the real issue. Yet, since there is no other answer and it did work, please write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: i know, but im not sure if it is possible to do this with an relative layout as you need two relations of your imagebutton to the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if these elements are just next to each other, you can use a linear layout and set the gravity to right. the linear layout automatically pushes the elements.

in relative layout all elements are "relative" to another element or the parent view, but just to one element for each direction. and if this object is "gone" the relation in this direction also is gone.